# How to use docker to setup kafka and spark-streaming on a Mac?

Tags: apache-spark, docker, apache-kafka

I just want to learn kafka and sparking streaming on my local machine (macOS Sierra).
Maybe Docker is a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like what you need is described [here](http://blog.antlypls.com/blog/2015/10/05/getting-started-with-spark-streaming-using-docker/)

> If you’ve always wanted to try Spark Streaming, but never found a time
>   to give it a shot, this post provides you with easy steps on how to
>   get development setup with Spark and Kafka using Docker

Example application [here](https://github.com/antlypls/spark-kafka-docker-demo)